# REGEXP_SUBSTR function to read date field from CSV file

Tags: sql, oracle11g, external-tables

I am writing a sql block which will ready csv formatted file using external table concept.

I have almost 20+ coluumns and code is reading all except filed which has date formatted data. dates are coming in this format 5/12/2014 12:12:22 ( month/day/year hour:minute:second)

this is kind of syntex i am using to read all string/varchar data. here V_LINE is just a variable that represents the count of rows,

```
V_CRT_DT := REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_LINE, '**[^,]+**', 1, 15);
```

could someone please help me on how to read a date formated data.

Comment: could someone please help me on this ..

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you show the table creation ddl and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to extract the column that contains a date and convert it into a date?

```
with data as
( select 'AAA,BBB,CCC,5/12/2014 12:12:22,DDD,EEE,FFF' str from dual)
select to_date(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, 4), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from data;
```

The regexp_substr() gets the 4th comma-separated field (the date/time), then to_date() converts it into a date.